# Bootstrap accordion questions

Tags: bootstrap-4, accordion

I am trying to create a Bootstrap (v4a) Accordion on a page of my WordPress site.

The accordion is as follows:

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Save money on your annual electricity bills
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">
        Save up to 90% on electricity bills for lighting – LED lights can save the average home or business a lot of money on annual costs.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Replace light far less often than other lighting types
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-block">
        With lifetimes of over 50,000 hours, LED lights last up to 10 times longer than traditional lights – maintenance costs are dramatically reduced and no flickering lights!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Select from a range of options to set the lighting mood
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-block">
        LED lights have been proven to improve concentration levels in working environments.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2 questions I have:

1. How do I ensure all elements are closed (collapsed) when the page loads (by default)?
2. How can I switch between an icon for open and one for closed?

Comment: to your Q1: `show` class of a card decides if it is close or open on load. If all cards does not have this class, all are closed.

Comment: to your Q2: if you need customized button for close / open, using script to add or remove the class `show` of each card and link these with your customized buttons.

Comment: BTW, v4a is not recommended if it is a newly built site. V4.0 was released officially.

Comment: how do i implement q2?

Comment: @TimothyAURA - q2 is a duplicate question, and there are many examples out there.. eg: https://www.codeply.com/go/506qHaPe9M

Comment: OK thank will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first panel, remove the "show" class to ensure all elements are closed:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
```